# Improve Performance of EPPlus cycling through worksheets

Tags: c#, excel, performance, epplus

I was looking for a bottle neck performance issue and I was surprised to discover that:

```
foreach (ExcelWorksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
}
```

Was eating close to 2/3 of the time.

I compared the above with this:

```
foreach (ExcelWorksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
    MyMethod(ws);
}
```

The one without `MyMethod` took: 7341, 5495, 5551 ElapsedMilliseconds

While the one with `MyMethod` took: 9969, 9285, 8096 ElapsedMilliseconds.

Is there any way to improve this? I'm only looking for sheets that are visible if that helps.

Code leading up to the above code block:

```
Pack = new ExcelPackage(file);
ExcelWorkbook wb = pack.Workbook;

Stopwatch testsw = new Stopwatch();
testsw.Start();

foreach (ExcelWorksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
    MyMethod(ws);
}

testsw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("testsw " + testsw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

for me,

```
var fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(sourceFile);
using (var p = new ExcelPackage(fi))
{
    var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var wslist = p.Workbook.Worksheets;
    foreach ( var ws in wslist)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ws.Name);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("sw " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

takes 209 milliseconds